# How to make decimal into a round number in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a small number game to practice and learn reactjs. The concpet is that the application will ask the player to think of a number between 0-1000. And the application will initially start guessing 500 (0+1000/2). And then the player gets to press buttons indicating if the number is higher or lower than the guess and of course a button if it's correct.

My issue is that the application use decimals instead of a round number.

Have done the same application in C# and now trying to get a feel for reactjs so been reading a bit on JS and react during my free time.

```
    min: number;
    max: number;
    guess: number;
    textValue: string;
```

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { min, max } = this.state
        this.setState({
            guess: min + max / 2
        })
```

My methods:

```
    Higher() {
        this.setState({
            min: this.state.guess,
            max: this.state.max,
            guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2)




        });



    }
    Lower() {
        this.setState({
            max: this.state.guess,
            min: this.state.min,
            guess: ((this.state.min + this.state.max) / 2)
        });

    }
```

What i want is that the value always will be a round number, but if for example if the guess is 5 and you press lower the new guess will be 2.5, if it's lower the guess is 1.25 and so on.

Comment: You can use `Math.round(num)` to round the number.

Comment: Also note that you should never read `this.state` within a `setState`, as the state can be updated asynchronously - [use the callback form of `setState` instead](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) if you need to make changes based on the previous state.

Comment: Nice got it to work now thank you. And thanks for the heads up!